# Is it possible for a conductor to run out of free electrons?

Tags: electricity, conductors

For example, imagine I apply a high voltage to a piece of conductor (copper) and make the electrons jump out of it like a automotive spark plug. Can the copper after a prolonged period of time run out of free electrons and stop generating sparks?

Comment: The number of electrons is finite, so why wouldn't that happen eventually?

Comment: Could you describe the setup in a bit more detail? A circuit will often be required and that causes replenishment of electrons constantly.

Comment: Exactly! The OP asked [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84776/is-it-possible-for-a-conductor-to-run-out-of-free-electrons) also on Chemistry SE. There he gave a little more details.

Comment: Yes, in a closed circuit thinks works fine. I would like to know what happens when the electrons are not replenished.

Comment: I know that current do not flow in an open circuit. But in my example scenery the electrons jump the conductor and are lost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [crossposting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/263383). If you don't receive an answer to your question at another site and want to ask it here, please request migration from there to here instead of duplicating the question.

Comment: I've already deleted the other question. I think I described the question better here.

Comment: How do you "*apply a high voltage to a piece of conductor*"? That would typically be done with a voltage source such as a battery - and then you have your electron source right there. I can't understand the exact problematic setup from your description - would you mind adding a sketch or more details of the setup?

Comment: A voltage of 12v produced by a battery is directed to a device that uses electromagnetism to increase the voltage to 100.000 volts this voltage is directed to tiny piece of copper that fires sparks. Will the piece of copper run out of electrons? I assume that this scenery will behave as described because it is more or less how sparks are generated in the combustion chamber of an automotive engine. If I am wrong let me know.

Comment: By applying a voltage to the piece of metal you are essentially pushing electrons onto it (assuming you do it relative to ground).

Answer (score 3):

Once an electron is removed from a body, the remainder is positively charged and attracts all the electrons around it. It only takes a tiny fraction of all free electrons in copper to be removed for the electric field generated by the now-charged conductor to overcome any electric field created by the "high voltage" you describe, thus preventing further removal of the electrons.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a calculation of such "a tiny fraction" !

Comment: The charge of the nuclei of copper is one faraday, about 100 000 coulomb per mole. The electrical capacitance of an object  of that size is of the order of 10 picofarads. With a voltage of 1 kV, the ratio of these charges becomes $10^{-8}/10^5 = 10^{-13}$.

Answer (score 2):

Copper contains $6\cdot 10^{23}$ free electrons per mole, that is $10^5$ Coulomb. One mole of Cu is about 8 $cm^3$ so a copper sphere of radius about 1.2 cm. The potential of such a sphere with a $10^5$ C charge would be +$10^{17}$ V, a number that does not make sense experimentally. The sphere would disintegrate long before you reach that value. So no, it is impossible to run out of conduction electrons.

Comment: In a highly ionized molecule, the dissociation would be called Coulomb explosion.

Comment: @Pieter The number did not make sense indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seems that free electrons can be smallest possible anions in solutions ([solvated electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvated_electron)), so I guess one can eventually run out of such free electrons as a result of electrolysis (for example, as the quantity of an alkali metal dissolved in ammonia reduces to zero after current in the electrolyte has been sustained for a long time).